# Add image Button Form C# using tags

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am trying to bind data in table and add Image button to Table cell

```
foreach (M1t4LicensesInfo obj in DataAfterSearch)
     {
         data += "<tr><td>" + SearchLicenseType.Items[obj.LicenseType] + "</td><td>" + SearchLicenseExtractedFrom.Items[int.Parse(obj.PublishingDesk)] +
                 "</td><td>" + obj.PublishingDate + "</td><td>" + obj.LicenseNumber + "</td><td>" + obj.PublishingDate+;   
        string Edit ="</td><td>"+"<asp:ImageButton  runat=\"server\" ImageUrl=\"~/Images/Edit.png\" />"+ "</td></tr>";                        
    data+=Edit 
}
```

all fields viewed in table except image button , so what is the problem 
and is there is another way to bind data with table

Comment: Did you try to break this down and see what is the problem? You are trying to create an asp:ImageButton tag, try `<img src="YOUR_IMAGE_PATH"`. If you really need an asp control, is not that way that you will create one, you have to create the objects and then get the html from them.

Comment: when i replace imageButton tag with img i can see the image i want. but i need it do be clickable using image or imagebutton any one no problem , how can i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to,

```
foreach (M1t4LicensesInfo obj in DataAfterSearch)
     {
         data += "<tr><td>" + SearchLicenseType.Items[obj.LicenseType] + "</td><td>" + SearchLicenseExtractedFrom.Items[int.Parse(obj.PublishingDesk)] +
                 "</td><td>" + obj.PublishingDate + "</td><td>" + obj.LicenseNumber + "</td><td>" + obj.PublishingDate+"</td><td>"+"<asp:ImageButton  runat=\"server\" ImageUrl=\"~/Images/Edit.png\" />"+ "</td></tr>";   
}
```

Assuming **DataAfterSearch** has required data.

Comment: After using this code got an Empty table cell. did u tried this code , i mean dose it work ?

Comment: I have not tried it because im not sure what **DataAfterSearch** contains so make sure **DataAfterSearch** is getting proper data. Code should work fine.